Wordpress Woocommerce User Role Edit Products ONLY
I have created a new user role with the following code in functions.php. But somehow the many options that can be set to true and false are overwhelming for me. My goal would be for the newly created user to only be able to create, edit products and upload media. Everything else should be prohibited if possible.
function my_role() {
    add_role(
        'shopmanager',
        'Shop Manager',
        array(
            'read'         => true,
            'edit_posts'   => true,
            'upload_files' => false,
            'manage_woocommerce'    => false,
            'manage_woocommerce_orders' => true,
            'edit_shop_order' => true,
            'edit_shop_order_terms' => true,
            'edit_shop_orders' => true,
            'manage_shop_order_terms' => true,
            'publish_shop_orders' => true,
            'read_private_shop_orders' => true,
            'read_shop_order' => true,
            'assign_shop_order_terms' => true,
            'delete_others_shop_orders' => true,
            'delete_private_shop_orders' => true,
            'delete_published_shop_orders' => true,
            'delete_shop_order' => true,
            'delete_shop_order_terms' => true,
            'delete_shop_orders' => true,
            'edit_others_shop_orders' => true,
            'edit_private_shop_orders' => true,
            'edit_published_shop_orders' => true,
            'read_private_pages'    => true,
            'read_private_posts'    => true,
            'edit_pages' => true,
            'edit_published_posts'  => true,
            'edit_published_pages'  => true,
            'edit_private_pages'    => true,
            'edit_private_posts'    => true,
            'edit_others_posts' => true,
            'edit_others_pages' => true,
            'publish_posts' => true,
            'publish_pages' => true,
            'delete_posts' => true,
            'delete_pages' => true,
            'delete_private_pages'  => true,
            'delete_private_posts'  => true,
            'delete_published_pages'    => true,
            'delete_published_posts'    => true,
            'delete_others_posts' => true,
            'delete_others_pages' => true,
            'manage_categories' => true,
            'manage_links'  => true,
            'moderate_comments' => true,
            'unfiltered_html'   => true,
            'upload_files'  => true,
            'export'    => true,
            'import'    => true,
            'manage_woocommerce_coupons'    => true,
            'manage_woocommerce_products'   => true,
            'view_woocommerce_reports'  => true
        ),
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_role' );


When you add new role using add_role() function, all permissions (capabilities) are set to false by default. So add only what you need. Use plugin such as User Role Editor if you are not sure what permission does and test or just google each permision. Also i would name it product manager not shop manager since you already have such role.
